# Terrain GeoMipMapping LOD - eliminating cracks

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using modern OpenGL with VBO's and indices etc.

First I load terrain from heightmap, then I divide it into blocks (128x128 in my case)
I load all vertices into VBO (for each terrain block)
And then i have 4 LOD levels - index tables - and it is pretty static.

While rendering i just pick block based on distance from camera

```
    if(distance > 768.0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cells[i].elementbuffer_lod4);
    else if(distance > 512.0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cells[i].elementbuffer_lod3);
    else if(distance > 128.0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cells[i].elementbuffer_lod2);
    else
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cells[i].elementbuffer_lod1);
```

And here I encountered a problem. Everything works fine but I have really ugly cracks between different lod level blocks. I found such pdf while googling: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/article_geomipmaps.pdf and i understand the idea but i don't really know how to implement it using VBO's (above). I would be happy to hear some ideas.

Comment: The simplest solution is probably just to copy the north row of vertexes from the next block south (and as appropriate for other directions) and make sure they line up on the NS/EW axis. You don't lose any data, just duplicate border verts into neighboring chunks so they have to line up.

Comment: Another simple solution would be to render two LODs where there is a seam.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the index buffer is independent from the block you are rendering. The same index buffer can be (re-)used for different blocks (I chose to highlight this because I do not get why you have this dependency towards cells[i] in your draw calls).

Then for one block you need to consider the level of detail (LOD) of its 4 neighboring blocks. If all 4 neighboring blocks have the same LOD as this one, then there is nothing more to do than what you are already doing. If this block is connected to a block with a lower LOD then you can apply the trick referenced in the article to hide the gaps. This means you will need additional pre-computed index buffers for these specific cases (either a full one each time, leading to possibly 2^4 = 16 different index buffers, or you can split the draw calls to handle the borders separately). Also the trick from the article only applies for a gap of one level maximum between adjacent blocks. You either need to make sure your level of details are spatially distributed in such a way that two neighboring blocks have only a gap of 1 in LODs. Or you find another trick / generalize this one. Masking skirts (extruding vertically the border of the block) can be used to hide wide gaps between blocks with different LODs.